# consolidate values on unique column

Tags: excel

I have an excel worksheet with 4 columns (Excel 2011)

```
id   item_name   owner   amount
1    House       David   500
2    Land        Ernest  600
1    House       David   400
3    Car         Frank   1000
2    Land        Ernest  700
```

I would like to remove duplicate rows based on the unique identifier, id in this case so that my sheet looks like this

```
id   item_name   owner   amount
1    House       David   900
2    Land        Ernest  1300
3    Car         Frank   1000
```

I have a worksheet with close to 113282 rows, the consolidate function can work this out well however, it requires me to manually use a pointer to select the range of cells. Filling in a cell reference using a named_range or even using other shortcuts to select the range does not give any output.

Is there a better way to do this

Comment: If this is a work that you often repeat, a good option would be to create your own macro using VBA If you have some knowledge about it. Otherwise, it is not difficult to understand and learn it, and if you work often on excel then it is a good investement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is solvable using Pivot Tables.
Select the Columns you wish to use as in the figure below
[image: Select the Columns to use]

Then select insert and click on recommend pivot table.

[image: select insert and then recommend pivot table]

Select sum by...

[image: Select sum by]

A new sheet will be added showing your grouped and summarised data

[image: sheet added showing grouped and summarised data]

I hope this solves your problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

Add this formula as an extra column (with a heading), changing the cell-ranges as appropriate:

```
=SUMIF($A$2:$A$6,A2,$D$2:$D$6)
```

If your data-table is complete (no blanks cells in column D) or you are using Excel 2010, you can type this formula once and double-click the Fill Handle (the little dot in the bottom-right corner) and it will fill/copy all the way down.

Copy and Paste-Special, Values this column. The data will already be selected, or you can click in the first data-cell and press `Ctrl-Shift-Down`. Then use the Data tab, **Remove Duplicates**. Tick every column except the *amount* one. Then delete the original *amount* column, replacing it with the new data from your added column.